# Output of find | xargs not redirecting to log file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find, xargs

I'm developing a Bash script which cleans up old data files periodically, and right now everything works except for the log file I'm trying to generate so I can see what it did.

The structure I'm using is (sorry for the variables):

```
find $datfold -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$month-*-data.dat" -printf "%f\n" | xargs tar -czvf $month-data.tar.gz >> $log
```

The tar.gz part is working fine, it's just not sending any output to the $log file. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know; however you may want to consider using tar's `--files-from` to read names directly from stdin instead of using xargs ex. `... -printf "%f\n" | tar --files-from=- -czvf "$month-data.tar.gz" >> "$log"` or `... -printf "%f\0" | tar --null --files-from=- -czvf "$month-data.tar.gz" >> "$log"`

Comment: I'll give that a try and see if it clears things up, thanks! Also, I noticed from your example that I had neglected to quote my variables at the end of my current command line, so I'm going to make sure that isn't causing a problem also.